# Have 2 flask pages that share a database, need to merge their models

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Need some guidance with this please. I have two pages or apps made with flask(+sqlalchemy) - one that acts as the front page and the other one that works as some kind of admin or extranet for the first one.

The apps use their own views and models but they share the same database and this is starting to mess things up when I try to make changes to the schema.

The way the project is setup is the next:
[file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8IJy.png)

```
/www
|- /flaskapp
| |- /flaskapp
|   |- models.py
|   |- views.py
|   |- form.py
|   |- init.py
|   |- oauth.py
|   |- /static
|   |- /templates
|   |- /flask
|
|- /extranet
  |-/extranet
    |- models.py
    |- views.py
    |- form.py
    |- init.py
    |- oauth.py
    |- /static
    |- /templates
```

So I need to merge the two pages' models into one model file so I can have more control over my database schema, migrations, etc. How can I do this in a proper way?

Comment: Where is the difficulty? Can we see some code? I usually make a models class where I place all my model code and just use that class for interaction with the database

Comment: Sqlalchemy can do JOIN operations, no?

Comment: To clarify: you are asking how to merge the two files where you define SQLAlchemy models, and not how to make changes to the database itself? Why not simply copy-and-paste?

Comment: @this-vidor yeah you are right, i want to merge the two files where i define the models; and yeah i have been considering copying and pasting but maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Like `cat flaskapp/flaskapp/models.py extranet/extranet/models.py > some/new/models.py`? (By the way, don't do this.)

Comment: If the two apps are truly separate, why are they using the same database?  Even if they are, why not use separate schemas?  If you're actually trying to use the database to integrate two applications - communicate in a different way

Comment: @Paul Becotte - the guy who made the pages took very bad design decisions, so im trying to fix the mess he left.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve. SQLAlchemy has a [declarative API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html) that allows you to sub-class some base (in Flask-SQLAlchemy, conventionally, `db.Model`); it then automatically builds [mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html) between those sub-classes and tables in your database.

As long as `db` refers to the same `SQLAlchemy` object in both `models.py` files (e.g., has been imported from the same scope), mappings will be formed for the whole schema. If you need to run some sort of migration tool using a `db` object with the full set of mappings, you could write a module:

```
# combine_db.py

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import flaskapp.models # imports `db` from combine_db
import extranet.models # imports `db` from combine_db
```

Then your migration tool can import `db` from `combine_db`!

If you don't like the circular-import approach, you can try wrapping your model sub-class definitions in a function, which you can import from `flaskapp` and `extranet` at the top of the file, and later call with `db` as an argument. (I haven't tested this.)

Comment: I set up a global db object- then so long as you import that before you import the models in the app file, everything will work properly, but it is more complicated that way.

Comment: @PaulBecotte What is more complicated than what?

Comment: Sorry, that was not very clear.  What I meant to say was that having multiple model files that depend on a single declarative base is more complicated than having a single file.  This is because you can break things with import order being wrong somewhere (or forgetting to import one model file in a unit test or something).

Comment: @PaulBecotte Sure, although generally speaking it can help a project's maintainability if insular parts of the codebase live in different files. OP is asking about a particular case where two projects they've inherited share a database, with models defined in two different places. The obvious objection to simply concatenating the two files is that, without a re-organization of the projects' file structure, changes in either `models.py` would have to be synched across projects, which would be a pain and could lead to some mystifying bugs if ever skipped.

Comment: @this-vidor - You seem to be on the right track of what my problem is. As you mention without a proper re-organization of the project file structure, the maintenance of the project itself is a pain and it actually leads to mystifying bugs. I read your answer and seems to be a good place to start, it is not totally clear to me yet but i'm gonna give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: @MarioV Can you explain what is unclear about this approach?

Comment: @this-vidor - Yeah, what it's kinda unclear is where should i add or place this module in my code/file structure?

Comment: @MarioV You are right that this approach doesn't make sense using the circular imports. If you use functions you could place the script anywhere. I'mgoing to test it out myself.